# Cumulative sum in the decreasing order in R

Tags: r, frequency, cumulative-sum, decrement

I have a data table below.

```
Idle_min <- c(1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8)
Freq <- c(16, 11, 5, 7, 3, 1)

df <- data.frame(Idle_min, Freq)
```

I want to obtain the cumulative frequency and add it as a new column, but it should be in descending order. That means, the first row should represent the total of Freq, then the second row represents Total-16, and so on.

So the output I expected for the dummy data above should look like this.

| Idle_min | Freq | cumulative |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 16 | 43 |
| 2 | 11 | 27(43-16) |
| 3 | 5 | 16 (27-11) |
| 5 | 7 | 11 (16-5) |
| 6 | 3 | 4 (11-7) |
| 8 | 1 | 1 (4-3) |

How did I suppose to obtain the cumulative in the decreasing order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `rev`erse on the column before doing the `cumsum`

```
df$cumulative <-  with(df, rev(cumsum(rev(Freq))))
```

-output

```
> df
  Idle_min Freq cumulative
1        1   16         43
2        2   11         27
3        3    5         16
4        5    7         11
5        6    3          4
6        8    1          1
```